# MPAndroid multiple Barchart multiple lables not displaying line by line

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid multiple Barchart where there are more than 20 BarDataSets. So, there will be more than 20 labels. I want to display each of the label clearly, line by line. But only 3 or 4 are appearing in a single and rest are absent . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
mChart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);